# Drupal Webform Radio button slider?

Tags: theming, nodes, webforms, javascript

I have created a webform in Drupal. It has a pagebreak after every question.

What I want to achieve is the following: When someone clicks on a radio button, the next question should slide up without the user clicking the next page button.

I have tried with theming, but I am not very experienced with Drupal, PHP, or jQuery.

[This is the link](http://tinyurl.com/d8rtjlq) to my webform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to your page something like

```
<script>
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-radio').click(function() { $('#edit-next').click(); });
  });
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
</script>
```

This is better done by adding a .js file via `drupal_add_js()`. Be aware that, since you are forcing your user to submit a form, you should provide a way to get back and resubmit a different choice.

Comment: hi thanks for ur help i have actually done that but it keeps going backwords after one question also i have radio buttons with text field which a person has to fill in the text and hen press next page on some of the questions

Comment: I edited the answer to solve your "going backwards" problem. I didn't notice that you actually have two submit buttons in your forms after the first. To address your other question, you need to have a different class attached to your radio buttons that you need to perform automated next behavior, and put that in place of the `$('.form-radio')` selector.